# Can a physical disk be moved from a PERC to a SAS controller non-destructively?

Tags: dell, dell-perc

I have some disks attached to a PERC H800. Since it unfortunately does not have a proper passthrough/JBOD mode, each physical disk is mapped to a 1-disk RAID 0 virtual disk. My question is- can those disks can be moved to being directly connected to a SAS controller without destroying the data on the disk?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. They cannot. Virtual disk metadata is still on the disk, even though it's a RAID 0, so you won't be able to retain that information once connected to a SAS HBA.

Answer (score 3):

Well the moving them won't hurt, trying to use them on the other hand...

The raid controller will have added some metadata. I'm not 100% certain what PERC RAID controllers do internally, if they add their meta data to the beginning of the disk, at the end or both.

A single disk RAID 0 volume would have appeared as the original disk minus some reserved space for the raid controllers metadata.

The disk of single disk RAID 0 volume could appear on your SAS controller as regular disk with a normal partition table and all data intact, plus a little bit of garbage at the end of the disk which was the raid controllers metadata.

If the metadata was added at the start of disk, the partition table will not be stored in LBA 0, but shifted a bit, and the first sectors will hold the metadata describing the RAID array. On your SAS controller it will appear as an unformatted disk.

You could try if recreating the partition table and starting the first partition at LBA 512 or 1024 results in a valid disk layout, but I wouldn't expect a quick positive result.

Comment: Under Linux, it should be possible to assemble the RAID with "mdadm --build md-device --level=Y ... devices" if we knew where the superblocks are, specifying all the values directly. Does anyone know the disk layout of Perc RAID 0 (and other levels)?